# Slow mysql connection for new fresh wamp install

Tags: database-connection, wampserver

I just installed new fresh Wamp server. I can go to http://localhost very fast but not with http://localhost/phpmyadmin. It takes several seconds for onload time (please see attached image). There is no databases. I re-installed another one but issue is still there. My machine is enough good to run (8GB RAM). 
Would you please advice me how to fix this problem. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Thats not slow, its about standard. Remember everything that is happening is happening on one PC.

Comment: I tested phpmyadmin on other machine. It takes only below 1s (onload time). In this case, it's about ~8s. What happened?

Comment: You could try changing the phpMyAdmin config file `\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.4\config.inc.php` to make it connect to MySQL using the ip address rather than `localhost` change this parameter `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`

Comment: Thank you, RiggsFolly. It works perfect on Chrome. But there is a unresponsive script issue in Firefox. The browser is stopped by "js/get_scripts.js.php?token=f82f955bdfb2ff8671f3cab75b58a311&scripts[]=jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js&scripts[]=ajax.js&scripts[]=keyhandler.js&scripts[]=jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js&scripts[]=jque...". It may Firefox issue. I will research the solution.